# Change the URL with a GET method

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to submit some selected fields to the URL with a GET method ?

by clicking on a button, I want to put a string on the URL, but using a GET method.

expected result:
test.html?test=11,13,21,34&somewords=1,2,3&demo=2

Comment: Can be done in plain HTML with a [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_method_attribute). Just submitting the form with JS might be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Example :

```
 function submit() {
   var test = document.getElementById('test').value;
   var demo = document.getElementById('demo').value;
   var somewords = document.getElementById('somewords').value;

   var url = 'test.html?test=' +test + '&somewords=' + somewords +  '&demo=' + demo;
   console.log(url); // test.html?test=1,2,3,4&somewords=noting&demo=2

    // Code for get request 
 }
```

HTML

```
 <input type="text" value="1,2,3,4" id="test">
 <input type="text" value="noting" id="somewords">
 <input type="text" value="noting" id="dummy">
 <input type="text" value="2" id="demo">
 <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Live example : https://jsbin.com/cayude/edit?html,js,console,output

Hope this helps. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

A simple form would most likely do

```
<form action="test.html" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="test">
    <input type="text" name="somewords">
    <input type="text" name="2">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in *changing the displayed URL*, use [History#pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method).

```
history.pushState(null, null, formatURL(query));
```

If you actually want to navigate to a different page,

```
window.location.href = formatURL(query);
```

Assuming `formatURL` is a small helper utility that formats a querystring URL like what you've provided.